# How to handle an error in a "Model" class in MVC ASP.NET, to do with null session vars

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3, C#, Razor, .NET4

I use a session variable in my Model constructor. Sometimes it can be null, mainly due to recycling of the AppPool. I need to catch the "null" error of the session and ideally redirect to another action ie Error/Index. However I am in model, and I am not sure whether one can redirect out of a model class.

my Code:

```
        try
        {
            intOrderId = (Int32) System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["OrderId"];
            intSupplierId = (Int32) System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SupplierId"];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          // Redirect to Error/Index ?????
        }
```

I have a feeling that I may have to set a property in the model to highlight the error, and then have the controller's action inspect this and act accordingly, howowever I have loads of actions that call this model, so I am not wanting to do this. I would rather react to this error in one place.

Many thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried using "return RedirectToAction", but it could not resolve it. I seem to have replied to a comment that has now disappeared ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using try/catch to handle empty values, why not check before you read?

```
if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["OrderId"] != null)
   && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SupplierId"] != null)
{
    intOrderId = (Int32) System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["OrderId"];
    intSupplierId = (Int32) System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SupplierId"];
}
else
{
   //Throw an exception that the controller can catch: NullReferenceException or InvalidCastException.
   //Or return a specific value to indicate that an error occured
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes totally understand your logic. In the end I went for a base controller which checks the sessions first, and this can do a redirect, and I write it once. An Idea by Nick Olsen.